# ddcci module suddenly stopped working

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, kernel-modules

comman i tried

```
sudo modprobe ddcci
```

syslog

```
Jul 18 13:59:17 phoenix systemd-modules-load[393]: Inserted module 'ddcci' 
Jul 18 13:59:17 phoenix kernel: [2.991677] ddcci: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel. 
Jul 18 13:59:17 phoenix kernel: [2.991697] ddcci: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
```

> I am using ubuntu 20.04 with i3wm

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself
ddcci loads two modules actually

```
MODULES := ddcci ddcci-backlight
```

so we need to load both modules

```
sudo modprobe ddcci
sudo modprobe ddcci-backlight
```

this fixed the issue

I will keep this post... so that anyone having this issue find it helpful